# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function session_start()

Tags: php

Full Error:

```
2021/03/20 08:04:37 [error] 18#18: *224 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function session_start() in /home/container/webroot/cdn.sappy.ga/session.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/container/webroot/cdn.sappy.ga/session.php on line 3" while reading response header from upstream, client: 144.76.145.230, server: cdn.sappy.ga, request: "GET /session.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "cdn.sappy.ga"
```

I am using Nginx and when i try to access my register.php this happens. Checked my php.ini file to no avail. Please help.

Comment: what's your php vesion?

Comment: PHP-FPM Version 7.3.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Nginx had problems with php so I switched to Apache and it worked flawlessly. Also now I am using PHP 7.4 instead of 7.3, so maybe that had something to do with it but thats all.